# Underscore.js _.where finding sub objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a data object with nested arrays. I'm wondering if Underscore can find the value inside an array inside the object.

Example:

```
var data = {
  'a': 'value',
  'b': 'value2',
  'c': [ 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
}

_.where(data, { c: 'value4' });
```

Comment: But that's a different data structure, why would it work?

Comment: He wants an `in`/`contains` operator.

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to sort all my records based upon the nested array value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `_.filter()` instead:

```
_.filter(data, function(item){
  return _.contains(item, "value4");
});
```